# Can Watson Discovery Service return only the relevant paragraph from a large pdf for a given query

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-discovery

I have ingested a pdf document about 60 pages and the requirement is to return only the paragraph that matches the given query. Currently, the complete text from document is being returned. I tried out various samples and wondering if this is possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get exact answers instead of the whole document using Watson Discovery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41801660/how-to-get-exact-answers-instead-of-the-whole-document-using-watson-discovery)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few approaches to try. 
You may want to try chunking the documents into smaller segments.

Alternatively there is a new feature that may help you called Passage Retrieval and Relevancy Training. There is a YouTube video released on May 18th 2017 that discusses this.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8BiuQKPQZJk

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This question is a duplicate of [How to get exact answers instead of the whole document using Watson Discovery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41801660/how-to-get-exact-answers-instead-of-the-whole-document-using-watson-discovery)

One of the answers:

> You are correct that today Discovery service returns entire documents
>   for a matched query, ranked by relevance to the query.