# Import Possible Answer Units into Watson Discovery

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, wit.ai, dialogflow-es, watson-discovery

I have a follow up question off of the question here:

[How to get exact answers instead of the whole document using Watson Discovery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41801660/how-to-get-exact-answers-instead-of-the-whole-document-using-watson-discovery)

One of the answers mentioned using the Document Conversion Service to create Possible Answer Units (PAUs) within my document. When I do this and upload this large JSON file that contains all of the PAUs, Discovery still returns the entire document that contains all of the PAUs, which I guess is expected.

To complete the solution, I assume I would have to break down each individual PAU into its own document. Does Discovery have a built in tool to do this, or do I need to write my own script?

(Ideally the script would contain some reference to the original file name/metadata and maintain the hierarchical structure that the Document Conversion Service created from my Header definitions)

Answer (score 0):

Watson Discovery doesn't provide the service of giving some section of document as an answer to your query.

If you have such things in your mind, I would suggest you to use [Retrieve and Rank](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/retrieve-rank/index.html) service, which basically helps you to train watson and to get expected answer section from your provided documents.

Note: *R&R service uses Document Conversion service internally*

Comment: Thank you for answering, but this doesn't really answer my question. I understand the Retrieve and Rank tool is more apt for my situation currently.

However, I would like to use the Discovery tool since it is the tool that will be getting more strategic focus and improvements. I imagine in the coming months there will be a lot of improvements and new features. I would like to take advantage of them as they come.

With that in mind, I am trying to implement a work-around and was wondering if there is a built in utility to do so. In my research I haven't found one. Are you aware of any?

Answer (score -1):

Now you can use the new passage retrieval feature to do that. It is available as "Include matching passages" in the WDS tooling or in the [API reference](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/discovery/api/v1/#query-collection)

Passages query boolean A boolean that specifies whether the service returns a set of the most relevant passages from the documents returned by a query. The default is false.

Note: The passages parameter works only on private collections. It does not work in the Watson Discovery News collection. "